# Sending JMS messages from python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, jms, spring-jms

Tring to send a JMS message from python 2.7.
but, I can't find how to do it.
JMS
Is there such an option?
Is there s simple tutorial for that?

Comment: JMS is an API specification so every implementation is different.  Which broker are you trying to send your message to? Lots of message brokers which implement JMS also support other protocols like STOMP and AMQP, both of which have Python bindings. Do you really want to send a "JMS" message (whatever that means)?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at these two links. The Pypi link was last updated in 2006, however, so be careful with use:

https://pypi.org/project/pyhjb/

https://docs.spring.io/spring-python/1.2.x/sphinx/html/jms.html